# Using quotes for storing values in Redis

Tags: java, redis, key-value

Is there any difference in storing a number as an absolute values, vs. as a string, in Redis?

For example, assuming the existence of a set key called `news:10:count`, given the following 2 statements,

```
sadd news:10:count 1200
sadd news:10:count "1200"
```

is there any difference between them?

More generally, is there a difference in using quotes for storing values? It seems that the command-line interpreter does not require them, at least if there are no spaces in the value being added.

Answer (score 0):

Values that could be converted to integer(no quotes) would be stored as binary data by redis's int encoding, a integer would cost [1-8] bytes in memory, that's a reason why redis is memory efficient when saving integer data.

And redis-cli would trim the quotes in your case. There is no difference if you send the two commands in redis-cli.